# Why links not working in PhoneGap?

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-build

This trouble affects all loaded resources (internal links, img, css, js). I'm tried use this code for load css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
```

But he work only if I connected to server via browser. When I connect via PhoneGap app on phone, resources not loading.

After it, I tried this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
```

And the same result..

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

if your css file is in the www\css folder then use:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />`

this is how I got mine to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the In App Browser Plugin.

```
plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb"
```

Then run...

```
window.open("http://www.sitename.com", '_system');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `css` folder is inside the `www` folder and then remove the first slash `/`, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
```